# How to dim LED monitors to that of CCFL monitor

Tags: display

LED monitors are too bright for my eyes and give me head aches.
I've reduced the brightness and contract on the monitor and in the video cards settings but yet it's still too bright.

How can I reduce the dimness of a LED back litted monitor to that of a CCFL monitor?
Is there is a special screen filter I could place over it, or should I just buy a CCFL monitor?

For a better comparison view this video. [CCFL vs LED Video:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uY2-Xrx_zU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Human eyes can cope comfortably with a wide range of brightness. Wikipedia says that a typical overcast day provides an illuminance of 10,000 - 25,000 lux. A full moon on a clear night provides an illuminance of only 0.25 lux.

Therefore it may be that the cause of your discomfort is that the *contrast* with ambient lighting is too high. If you can't decrease the LED brightness, you could instead illuminate the surrounding work area with a bright desk lamp.

Comment: Pretty much this. If you want to read the text easily, and see everything sharp, you need to use the correct contrast/brightness values. A light source will always help.

Answer (score 0):

I illuminate my computer desk with natural light. I turn the blinds up so that it doesn't put a glare on my screen. It hurts my eyes when I use my monitor with an artificial light on above my head.